# raku grammar problem when trying to define a grammar for markdown

Tags: raku

I'm using the following code to parse a subset of Markdown text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl6

use v6;

my @tests = '',         #should print OK
            "\n\n\n",   #should print OK
            'alpha',    #should print OK
            '1234',     #should print OK
            'alpha123', #should print OK
            'a simple test without a heading and whitespaces and 123 numbers',                                                  #should print OK
            'a simple test without a heading with punctuation, whitespaces and 123 numbers.',                                   #should print OK
            'a simple test without a heading with punctuation, whitespaces, 123 numbers, quotes\' ", braces (){}<>[], \/.',     #should print OK
            'a simple test with a # in the middle',                                                                             #should print OK
            "#heading",         #should print FAILED
            "#heading ",        #should print FAILED
            "#heading\n",       #should print OK
            "#heading \n",      #should print OK
            "#heading\nand a text",                     #should print OK
            "#heading\nand\na\ntext\nwith\nnewlines",   #should print OK
            "#heading1\nand text\n#heading2\nand text"  #should print OK
            ;

grammar markdown_ltd {
    rule TOP {
        [ <text> | <headingandtext>+ ]
    }
    rule text {
        <textline>*<lasttextline>?
    }
    rule textline {
        <textlinecontent>? [\n]
    }
    rule lasttextline {
        <textlinecontent>
    }
    rule textlinecontent {
        <[\N]-[\#]> [\N]*
    }
    rule headingandtext {
        <heading> [\n] <text>
    }
    rule heading {
        [\#] [\N]+
    }
}
for @tests -> $test {
    my $result = markdown_ltd.parse($test);
    say "\nTesting '" ~ $test ~ "' " ~ ($result ?? 'OK' !! 'FAILED');
}
```

The purpose pf this grammar is to detect headings and regular text.
However, there is some error in the code such that the included tests do not lead to the expected behavior. When I run the script, I get the following output:

```
Testing '' OK

Testing '


' OK

Testing 'alpha' FAILED

Testing '1234' FAILED

Testing 'alpha123' FAILED

Testing 'a simple test without a heading and whitespaces and 123 numbers' OK

Testing 'a simple test without a heading with punctuation, whitespaces and 123 numbers.' OK

Testing 'a simple test without a heading with punctuation, whitespaces, 123 numbers, quotes' ", braces (){}<>[], \/.' OK

Testing 'a simple test with a # in the middle' OK

Testing '#heading' FAILED

Testing '#heading ' FAILED

Testing '#heading
' FAILED

Testing '#heading 
' FAILED

Testing '#heading
and a text' FAILED

Testing '#heading
and
a
text
with
newlines' FAILED

Testing '#heading1
and text
#heading2
and text' FAILED
```

Which differs from the output I expected.

Comment: `use Grammar::Tracer;` or `use Grammar::Debugger;` is a good first step to trying to figure out such things. (I would try it myself but it is 4am and I have to get up in a few hours.)

Comment: I think you might want to try using token instead of rule because rules silently swallow whitespace – https://docs.raku.org/language/grammars#Rules
You might also have more success with start and end of line anchors than with [\n] and [\N] – https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Anchors

Comment: awesome! thanks, changing all rules to token fixed the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @donaldh for pointing me to the right direction!
By changing all occurences of `rule` to `token` fixed the issue!